# Difference between "docker kill" and "docker exec -t <container-name> kill -- 1"?

Tags: docker

When the docker container is running with `--restart unless-stopped` argument, `docker kill` sends a `SIGKILL` and kills the PID 1, which stops the container and the container is not restarted after that; `docker exec -t <container-name> kill -- 1` also sends a `SIGKILL` and kills the PID 1, but the container is automatically restarted.

Why does this happen? Both commands are trying to achieve the same functionality, that is to kill the PID 1.

On reading [docker restart](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy), neither `always` nor `unless-stopped` restart the container. Then, why does kill -- 1 restart the container?

Answer (score 2):

`docker kill` is used to force stop a running container.

`docker exec -t <container-name> kill -- 1` is used to "soft" stop a specific process inside a container.

---

The -- 1 argument specifies the signal to send, in this case, the SIGTERM (a request to the program to terminate) signal.

This command sends the SIGTERM signal to the process with PID 1 inside the container.

---

When you run your application inside a Docker container, it will be assigned process identifier (PID) 1. This particular PID is special in the Unix world. PID 1 is assigned to the very first process that the kernel starts, therefore it takes a special role in the system.

The default action is ignored when receiving signals, which means your process will not implicitly terminate on SIGINTor SIGTERM. Usually, operating systems terminate your process when processes receive SIGINTor SIGTERM.

---

Process with PID 1 is the init process. That stays true in a pid namespace or a container: this pid 1 cannot be killed with SIGKILL because it has no KILL signal handler defined, contrary to any other userland process.

If you really want to kill it, you have to kill it from the host. Running on the host (with enough privileges, probably root):

`docker exec -t <container-name> kill -- 1`

Meaning, The process will not die, but be interrupted and probably restart.

Comment: Can you explain an implicit termination vs explicit termination? You are saying PID 1 is special and ignores implicit SIGTERM. So, I am assuming kill -- 1 sends an explicit SIGTERM which is considered by the PID 1? Why though? I am not able to understand.

I do understand that on kill nothing must be restarted but on soft stop it must be because restart option was explicitly specified.

Comment: @xihare I have updated my answer for your question,
It is a good question BTW :-)

Comment: Okay, I understand that since there is no kill handler, PID 1 cannot be killed. So, it will get interrupted and restart. But you haven't answered by above question in case of `docker kill`,    
1)  Why does PID 1 consider the SIGTERM signal when you say the default action, which is graceful shutdown, is ignored by PID 1 as it is special?